Is there a way to show all npm package dependency versions for each package version?
I am working on upgrading an npm project version by version for the main packages, going v1 -> v2 -> v3 etc. However, I also need to validate the project runs at each upgrade. The problem is that all of the packages that have the main package as a dependency also need to be upgraded version by version, but there is no easy way I can tell to know what to upgrade them to. Ideally, I'd like to run an npm command to see each version of the failing package and the corresponding version of the main package it requires so I know what to update it to specifically. Is this possible?

For more context, my current strategy has been to run npm install, see what dependency is failing due to its dependency on an older version of the main package, look up that package in npmjs.org, and move it up versions one at a time until it's at a version compatible with the new main package version.

Use the cli command npm ls -all. See the link for documentation.
See also

npm audit
npm update
npm explain

